# Configuring touchpad on Acer Aspire-VN7-791G with Linux Mint, changes are not accepted

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, touchpad, xinput, acer

I'm trying to configure my touchpad by adding options in a the newly created file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf`. The file looks like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "enable HorizTwoFingerScroll"
        MatchDriver "synaptics"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "1"
EndSection
```

however, this change does not seem to be accepted after a reboot. Using `synclient -l` reveals `HorizTwoFingerScroll` is still set to `0`.
Setting the value via `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll 1` makes it work, but after restarting the value is reset again.

I already deactivated the gnome settings deamon via `dconf-editor`, because I thought that might be the problem, but that did not make any difference.

Another strange thing is that the touchpad is not recognized by the system 
anyway. Using `sudo evtest` or `xinput` shows that there is an unknown device. This is the output of `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳     UNKNOWN                               id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD WebCam                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Acer WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Using `xinput --list-props 11` shows that this is indeed a synaptics touchpad. Output:

```
Device '    UNKNOWN':
    Device Enabled (137):   1
    --- lots of Synaptics Options ---
    Device Product ID (257):    1739, 10608
    Device Node (258):  "/dev/input/event13"
```

The only thing that works is adding `synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll 1` as startup application, but thats not how I want it to be solved. And I don't want to add a startup application for every option I'd like to set. Using the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf` seems like the best way.

Now my question is: What do I need to do in order to make my changes in this file be accepted?

My Kernel version is `4.2.0-18-generic`.